# Detect if the Accessibility Inspector is enabled on the Simulator

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uikit, accessibility

I have some graphical classes which support Voice Over for accessibility. Calculation of the accessibility elements can sometimes be expensive, so we only add the accessibility elements if Voice Over is running, by checking the value returned by the `UIAccessibilityIsVoiceOverRunning()` function and the `UIAccessibilityVoiceOverStatusChanged` notification, and this works fine.

However, if I want to debug my Voice Over accessibility elements on the Simulator using the *Accessibility Inspector* as explained [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/TestingAccessibilityOfiOSApps/TestAccessibilityiniOSSimulatorwithAccessibilityInspector/TestAccessibilityiniOSSimulatorwithAccessibilityInspector.html), I cannot do so because `UIAccessibilityIsVoiceOverRunning()` returns `NO` even when you have the *Accessibility Inspector* enabled.

Is there an equivalent of `UIAccessibilityIsVoiceOverRunning()` and `UIAccessibilityVoiceOverStatusChanged` for the Simulator's *Accessibility Inspector*?

I know I could conditionally disable the optimization test when compiling against the simulator, but if possible I would like to keep it, and only calculate the accessibility elements if the *Accessibility Inspector* is running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid detecting if the *Accessibility Inspector* is running on the Simulator is not currently possible.